# Passing a third party object as Command Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using a 3rd party tree element in my XAML from which I want to add elements to my own tree control. This is done via a button that is bound to a Command "TransferClick".
Now to get the elements from the 3rd party tree control I need to ideally pass it along as a command parameter, which is where I'm stuck.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <this:MeasurementConfig />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <SystemStorageUI:StorageChannelAndAliasBrowser x:Name="sdfBrowser"/>
        <TreeView x:Name="fileTree"/>
        <Button x:Name="trnsfrButton"
                Command="{Binding TransferClick}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, when I use `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` I get an object of type MeasurementConfig in the "Execute" method of my `RelayCommand : ICommand` class. This makes sense as it's my DataContext.
When I use `CommandParameter="{Binding sdfBrowser}"` I gete null.

How can I pass the "sdfBrowser" object along?

Comment: Have you tried `{Binding ElementName=sdfBrowser}`?

Comment: Can I somehow mark your Comment as the answer? This is spot on!  
It's a bit of a shame how close I came, though...

Comment: Sorry for the long time to answer, Holydays.... Comments can't be marked as answers. Feel free to either answer your own question and accept it or simply delete it.

Comment: Ok, will do that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the ElementName Keyword was missing:
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=sdfBrowser}" worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set window name in your window tag and pass window as parameter through `CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YourWindowName}"`. If you want only specific properties of your view you can implement interface with this specific properties in your view than bind window in CommandParameter as above but in viewModel get interface as parameter.